# Number as a default jquery plugin option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, settings

I have a little problem.
I'v set up some jquery plugin default settings:

```
defaults = {
    insdElmnts: 'img',
    cursorDistance : 10
};
function plugin (options) {
    this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
}
```

and i try tu use this one with `cursorDistance` like this:

```
_mark.css({
    left: 10 - this.settings.cursorDistance,
    top: 10 - this.settings.cursorDistance
});
```

but i have some error: Cannot read property 'cursorDistance' of undefined.
What is not right? Do i need add some units? Thx for help.

Comment: `settings` is undefined on `this`, read that error message very carefully. It's looking for a property  named 'cursorDistance' on `undefined`, and undefined obviously has no properties. this means `this.settings` is undefined.

Comment: `this` likely isn't what you think it is.

Comment: that's correct, stupid mistake, thx for advice guys, it help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If You developing jquery plugin - "this" inside of it means "jquery collection". When You call $(".element_class").plugin(); - inside of plugin function this will equal to $(".element_class"). To access every element of collection - you should use .each().

2) Use .data() method to associate some data with html element. Example of plugin:

```
(function($){  
   var defaults = {
       insdElmnts: 'img',
       cursorDistance : 10
   };

   $.fn.pluginName= function(options) {
      //here "this" means "jquery collection"
      return this.each(function () {
          //here "this" means "html element"
          var el = $(this);    
          el.data("settings", $.extend({}, defaults, options));
          /** do here something that you need **/
      });  
   };
})(jQuery);
```

3) Use .data method to extract data outside of plugin:

```
_mark.css({
    left: 10 - _mark.data("settings").cursorDistance,
    top: 10 - _mark.data("settings").cursorDistance
});
```

But better try to write good plugin that will do all needed work itself.